# Rest API - Save Searched Results

Tags: c#, api

I'm working with an Angular project, where the user would be able to search through the search field or filters and retrieve data from the database. The user should be able to save these searched values into a database table by clicking the save button. The sql table that I will create will contain these 4 properties of the NewFilter class.

My question is related to the c# part, how can I implement an API that could  save serached items?

I have this class with these propertie, which identifies the searched values.

```
 public class NewFilter
{
    public int FilterId { get; set; }
    public string IndicatorList { get; set; }
    public int ROSFilter { get; set; } // quick access filters
    public string DatabaseList { get; set; }
}
```

I use rest api and postman for testing the API endpoints, which later should be passed into the Angular part.

Comment: Like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-create-method
Then use angular to call your API?

Comment: Something like that, but this is an ASP.NET Core approach. the project that I am working on is based on Dapper. The database is created manually.

Comment: Okay, but your question concerns saving it to the database or passing it to you API controller?

Comment: My question is related to the implementation of the api for the mentioned class, which can be tested via swagger/postman. Then I will use the endpoints from swager/postman to be passed into the angular function.